# Is there a way to build the same JavaFX app to a .exe with different build types?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I need to build a javafx aplication to a .exe file, to be used in 3 differents enviroments.

Now, before I build the application to each different enviroment I am changing every variable manualy, like urls, versions and tokens. I know that is a matter of time until I upload the wrong version to the wrong enviroment, so I really need a more automatic process to manage each version.

I read something about maven build profiles but i do not find a way to integrate this in the building of the exe file

This javaFx app is using maven and java10

To build the java code to an exe, I'm using Intellij

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The big problem is that java 10 is end of lifetime (EOL), so you should already work with java 11, this however is a little more complicated since JavaFx/OpenJfx is now separated. (see https://openjfx.io/)

Anyway to solve your complex needs you should think about a CI platform like as example gitlab CI.

This platforms (with the help of Docker Images) give you the tools you need to properly build and configure complex javaFX build targets and configurations.

But you have to build the .exe file on your own with tools like exe4j if you choose this path.

Side Tips:

- In my experience is a lot more easy to build java 11 applications
  with gradle instend of just maven since you gain a lot more
  flexiblity to solve complex problems
- If you stay on java 10 it would be much easier since Java11 + Openjfx
  11 required OS dependend builds. (but as I sayed it is EOL)